# Query with JPA returns incorrect data

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have a problem fetching the data from my database. The problem comes with a decimal type column. If I run the query from MySQL Workbench it returns this:

```
NAME        IMPORT      V   DATE
---------------------------------------------
TEST5       90.000000   2   2020-04-29
TEST5       90.000000   3   2020-04-29
TEST4       90.000000   2   2020-04-29
TEST4       90.000000   3   2020-04-29
```

But from my JAVA code I don't know the reason why it returns me:

```
NAME        IMPORT      V   DATE
---------------------------------------------
TEST5       90.000000   2   2020-04-29
TEST5       90.000000   2   2020-04-29
TEST4       90.000000   2   2020-04-29
TEST4       90.000000   3   2020-04-29
```

Both queries are simply a `SELECT * FROM TABLE;`. 
The type of column `V` is `DECIMAL`, but I do not understand the reason why some records do return them well and others do not. Add that when the insert is made, the values ​​are as shown in the WorkBench: 2 and 3

Comment: Please share your entity design and jpa query